# Photoshopのスクリプトでレイヤーを水平方向に反転させたい

Tags: javascript, photoshop

複数のレイヤーを一気に回転させるスクリプトは、下記のような形で記述しています。

```js
var docObj = activeDocument.artLayers;
for (var i=0; i<docObj.length; i++)
{
  if (!docObj[i].isBackgroundLayer)
  {
    docObj[i].rotate(90);
  }
}
```

この中に、水平方向に反転させるコマンドを入れ込みたいです。

Comment: キャンバス全体を反転させるのは `Document.flipCanvas` というメソッドがあるようですが、そうではなくレイヤーを反転させたいのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
たしかに、キャンバス全体を反転させることで、対応できました。
自分は、レイヤーごとに反転させるコマンドがあるのかなと思ってました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

編集→変形→拡大・縮小 Wの値を -100% と同等なら

```
activeDocument.activeLayer.resize(-100,100);
```